# Origin of “tout court”

Tags: etymology

According to the OED, [*tout court*](http://www.oed.com/view/Entry/203980?redirectedFrom=tout+court#eid163706549) means in short, in little, simply, without qualification or addition.

But [*tout*](http://www.oed.com/view/Entry/203978?rskey=HLzKrL&result=6&isAdvanced=false#eid) itself means to peep, peer, look out; to gaze.

So my question is how can “peep court” mean “in short”?

Comment: _Tout_ means _all_ as in _tout le monde_. I'm not sure where you're getting the definition of _peep_ from ... You can also try asking in french.stackexchange as it's basically a French expression.

Comment: @coleopterist  I have found that tout means peep in Oxford Dictionary .

Comment: Any OED definition will explicitly cite the French origin of the word.  How did you miss that?

Comment: @itsbruce Because I'm not quite familiar to French.

Comment: You don't have to be; it's an English dictionary.  That is, it explains *in English* that the phrase is French. If you had read the dictionary entry properly, you wouldn't have needed to ask here.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The entire phrase is French. As an adjective, *tout* means “all” In French, but as an adverb as it is here, *tout* means “quite”. It’s modifying the adjective *court*, which means “short”.  The longer OED entry for the adverbial sense reads in part:

> ǁǁ ***tout*** `/tu/`, *adv., sb.*<sup>4</sup>, and *a*.
>
> Etymology: Fr.
>
> **A.** *adv*. Quite, entirely: ***tout au contraire*** `/tut o kɔ̃trɛr/`, quite the contrary; ***tout court*** `/tu kur/`, in short, in little, simply, without qualification or addition; ***tout de suite*** `/tu də sɥit/` *de suite* in sequence, at once, immediately; cf. **toot sweet**; ***tout seul*** `/tu sœl/`, quite alone, on its (or his, etc.) own; ***tout simple, simplement*** `/tu sɛ̃pl/`, `/sɛ̃pləmɑ̃/` quite simply, just that. /tu/, adv., sb.<sup>4</sup>, and a.

By the way, the OED has **seven** completely different entries for the word *tout*; in other words, it has seven different *tout* words. Your “peep” definition just doesn’t apply to this one.

Comment: Okay, you're right, but why a French phrase appears in an English Dictionary?

Comment: Because it's sometimes used in an English context, as are several foreign expressions.

Comment: @Popopo This happens all the time. You will also find words like *vis-à-vis, façade, fiancée,* and *naïve* in an English dictionary, because people use them in English.

Comment: @Popopo there is "dance macabre" or "macabre dance" too.

Answer (score 1):

With the meanings the OED gives it in its separate entry, *tout* is an English verb, rhyming with 'spout'. In the expression *tout court* it's a French adjective, rhyming, in an English pronunciation, with 'you'.

**EDIT**: A French adverb, not adjective.

Comment: Yes, quite right. Now changed.